# Good coding practices for __int128 drop-in replacement class

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

While porting some crypto code from GCC to MSVC, I run into the old problem of MSVC not supporting the __int128 data type.

So, I decided to write a lightweight **drop-in replacement** class for the 128-bit integer datatype in MSVC, in order to avoid altering the original GCC crypto code as much as possible (it is big!).

I have overloaded/implemented all of the arithmetic operators (division and modulo were a bitch) and all other operators, which are being used by the original GCC code, except for the unary "address of" operator (&), because **[this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719)** stated: "*The unary address-of operator should never be overloaded.*"

Also, I have a problem with the sizeof() keyword because the original GCC code often uses sizeof() on __int128 sized variables.

What are the good coding practices to write such user-defined datatype in MSVC C++ ?

Why the "address of" operator should never be overloaded?

How should I write my __int128 class so I can rely on `sizeof(MyInt128)==16` when MyInt128 is of the __int128 type, implemented by my drop-in replacement class ?
Is avoiding virtual functions and the presence of VFTP, enough?  What about padding and the memory alignment of the 128-bit integer storage?

What are the other gotchas lurking out there when trying to implement my own drop-in __int128 user defined data type?  ...casts?

P.S.
Bigint libraries (GMP, Boost, etc..) all do it differently.

Comment: If your class is "standard layout" then you guarantee its size.  I presume you have, as the only non-static data members, `uint64_t` (loword) followed by `int64_t` (hiword) ?

Comment: "Crypto code" generally used byte arrays, not 128-bit integers.

Comment: Zaph, the one I am porting uses one and the other.

Comment: Ben, correct.  I have a union of char[16] and struct of loword and hiword, just like you wrote.